# Spring webflux reactive api always returning 404 error

Tags: spring, rest, post, http-status-code-404, spring-webflux

Here is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.test"

        })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
        Properties props = BootProperties.forService(
                "test", "test", "test");
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(
                Application.class)
            .properties(props)
            .run(args);
    }
```

RestController

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private ARepository aRepo;

    PersonController(ARepository aRepo) {
        this.aRepo = aRepo;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/books", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<VO> createBook(@Valid @RequestBody VO vo) {
        return apply(vo);
    }

    public Mono<VO> apply(VO vo) {
        Mono<VO> alternate = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            return aRepo.findById(vo.getId1(), vo.getId2());
        }).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).next().map(n -> build(vo, n)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
    return alternate;
    }
```

Comment: can you please post how you are doing your request

Comment: http:/localhost:8080/app-env2/books
request body {"id1": "678",
"id2": "275"}

Comment: app-env2? try removing that

Comment: That’s context path

Comment: i dont see any defined context path in your code example